# undefined method `to_model' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following ActiveAdmin model

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :challenges

  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

and the following Challenge model

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subdomain
    belongs_to :admin_user

    has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

I defined the following method in my application.html.erb

```
 helper_method :all_admin_users

  def all_admin_users

    @users = AdminUser.all
  end
```

Adminuser has the following attributes :id,:name,:email
Now when i try to access the challenges of a particular User

```
<ul>
<% all_admin_users.each do |user| %>
<li> <%= link_to user.name ,user.challenges%></li>
<br />
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I get the following error "undefined method `to_model' for Challenge::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

here's my routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  get 'subdomains/index'

  get 'subdomains/edit'

  get 'subdomains/new'

  get 'subdomains/show'

  get 'home/index'




 root 'home#index'


 resources :challenges

 resources :subdomains
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Comment: error "undefined method `to_model' for #<Challenge::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc54980a2a8>"

Comment: It would be better if you edited your question and put the truncated sentence back in to the question rather than putting it into a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First in your `routes` file you need to add action to list users-challenged

In `routes.rb` at end add

```
get 'users/:user_id/challenges' => 'challenges#user_challenges', as: :user_challenges
# this way you will have action to view users challenges
# inside your challenges controller
```

In your `challenges_controller.rb` add action `user_challenges`

```
def user_challenges
  @challenges = Challenge.where(admin_user_id: params[:user_id])
end
```

Create view for this action, and display your challenges

Then you can create link for this action

```
<ul>
  <% all_admin_users.each do |user| %>
    <li> <%= link_to user.name , user_challenges_path(user.id)%> </li>
    <br />
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks
but this gives me all the challenges of all the users
i want the user names to be displayed and on clicking the user name 
i want it to direct to the challenges that belong to the clicked user

Comment: You want to redirect to list all challenges of that user ? show me routes folder

Comment: Thanks
I tried that 
but challenges_path gives me all the challenges of all users
what i want is challenges of that particular user??

Comment: It gives me a missing template error
and URL redirected to "http://localhost:3000/users/1/challenges"

Comment: You need to create view for that added action, as I have said

Comment: I just included render:index in user_challenges action and it worked
thanks a lot @Nermin

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `user.challenges` use `user.challenge`

**UPDATE**

```
<ul>
  <% all_admin_users.each do |user| %>
    <% user.challenges.each do |challenge| %>
      <li> <%= link_to user.name ,challenges_path(user_id: user.try(:id)) %></li>
      <br />
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

challenges_controller.rb

```
def index
  @challenges = Challenge.where(admin_user_id: params[:user_id])
end
```

Comment: thanks 
but i get the following error
"undefined method `challenge' for #<AdminUser>"

Comment: Do you have `admin_user_id` in `Challenge` table?

Comment: Yes@prashant
here's the list of columns  in Challenge table
["id", "title", "body", "input_format", "output_format", "constraints", "subdomain_id", "admin_user_id", "created_at", "updated_at"]

Comment: @prashanth
I tried user.try(:challenge)
but that doesn't redirect me to anywhere!!!!

Comment: I have updated the post, please go through it. Hope it helps! @pokiri

Comment: Thanks @prashanth
suppose i have 2 users and each user has two challenges
according to ur code 
it gives me links to all the 4 challenges,with the title names as USER NAMES
but what i need is that
U need to display the names of user(in this case only 2 users) and when we click on the user name it should redirect me to all the challenges of that particular user

Answer (score 0):

As addition to Prashant4020's answer - 
What You think about update User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
belongs_to :admin_user
...
```

and therefore

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :challenges
has_many :users
....
```